# Tile a rectangle with a custom shape in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Is there a way to fill an area tiling it with a custom shape?
Like we can do with

```
Image("SomeImage")
    .resizable(resizingMode: .tile)
```

but I want to be able to change the shape of an Image (like changing a circle size) I fill with dynamically. Something like an analogue of `VisualBrush` with a propper `TileMode` in WPF.

Using `ForEach` + `HStack`/`VStack` gives really poor performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image` has own content size, so can be tiled as-is, but `Shape` by design has no own size and fill all provided rectangle, so it is needed to specify which size to use for tiles.

Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoShapeTiling: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().fill(Color.blue)
            .tile(Circle(), of: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .clipped()
    }
}

struct TilingShape<S: Shape>: Shape {
    let shape: S
    let size: CGSize

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        for x in stride(from: CGFloat.zero, to: rect.size.width, by: size.width) {
            for y in stride(from: CGFloat.zero, to: rect.size.height, by: size.height) {
                let r = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), size: size)
                path.addPath(shape.path(in: r))
            }
        }
        return path
    }
}

extension View {
    public func tile<S: Shape>(_ shape: S, of size: CGSize) -> some View {
        self.overlay(TilingShape(shape: shape, size: size))
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to have. Works with Xcode 11.5 / macOS 10.15 as well.